# java regex search?

Tags: java, regex

Hi i need to search a string with in paragraph .Here the string may be a java regex .
How do i differentiate a regex and a ordinary string.
Please give some suggestions to achieve this?

Comment: You wanna search for occurrences of regular expressions in a given paragraph using regex? Bring down the constraints - what all can that regex contain?

Comment: A regex is a regex. There is no difference with a Java regex. Take a look at `Pattern.compile()` and `Mather` and `String.indexOf()`.

Comment: You can search for regex meta characters in the text to extract possible candidates. Use something like `[\\\-\]\^(){}+*]`

Comment: In your other post, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1706775/java-regex-regular-expression-to-split-a-paragraph-with-start-and-end, I stressed the importance of clearly communicating your problem clearly to others through a public forum as SO. You either didn't read it, or ignored the advice. I don't really care but realize that many people who might be able to help you simply disregard question like yours because they ar too vague.

Comment: Bart ... i am really sorry ..this is Sidharth ..i am very new to this kind of sites (StackOverflow) .. now onwards i will communicate my problem clearly for sure .. sorry for inconveniences Bart ...

Comment: hi  Martijn Courteaux ... the syntax for java regex and unix/perl regex differ from each other?

Comment: Hi  Amarghosh ... that solution will be a tedious work since the regex possibilities may be higher ..

Comment: hi Cheeso ..
ex :
  given string : \s*nameMyhjjj
  Paragraph : asdasdjaksdj asdasd asdasdas nameMy hdhddhdhnameMyhjjj

Here the given string contains character \s* or i need to consider this as a regex ?

Comment: Sidharth, no problem. Now, can you perhaps edit your original question and post the example(s) in it instead of posting them here in these small comment-boxes. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A regex *is* an ordinary string. For example, if you get given "a.b" should that match "axb" or not? It does if you treat it as a regular expression, it doesn't otherwise. If you want to *actually* search for just the value "a.b" then what would you want to be passed?

Where is the string coming from? Ideally, get that data source (whether it's the user or not) to tell you whether to use a regex or not.

Comment: actually the string is from user ..the user may or may not know regex pattern searching

Comment: Well only the user knows whether they expect "a.b" to match "axb" then. The user *has* to give you that information - e.g. by having a checkbox saying "Treat this as a regular expression", defaulting to false.

Answer (score 2):

Seems impossible. In fact words like `I`, `am`, `a` and `developer` are also perfectly valid regexes.

You need to tell first what patterns you'd expect to be regex patterns, then we can maybe suggest **another** regex pattern for this =)

Answer (score 0):

Use [escapes](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#bs)?

Comment: Who is the user? What are you actually trying to achieve? Please clarify your question and the problem you want to solve.