# java help! how do i read lines in file as paragraph and count words

Tags: java, paragraph

i want to read lines in a file as paragraph. for example if there are lines of text without empty space between them it should treat it as 1 paragraph and then i want to count the words.

So far it count the words correctly but doesn't recognise lines of text as a paragraph. Java beginner

```
Scanner file = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("/.../output.txt"));

int count = 0;

while (file.hasNextLine()) {
    String s = file.nextLine();

    count++;

    if(s.contains("#AVFC")){
        System.out.printf("There are %d words on this line ", s.split("\\s").length-1);
        System.out.println(count);
    }
}

file.close();
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1706775/java-regex-regular-expression-to-split-a-paragraph-with-start-and-end - possible duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

If a "paragraph" is defined as "a sequence of non-blank lines", then do as you're doing for individual lines, but add them up until you get to a blank line (or the end of the file), at which point you have your count for the just completed paragraph.  Remember to reset the sum when you finish a paragraph, to get ready for the start of the next one.  And you might need to deal with multiple blank lines in a row.

*Update*:  Instead of printing out the number of words in a line, save that number to a variable, say `wordsInLine`.  If that is 0, then you're done with a paragraph (unless `count` is 0, which means you haven't started a paragraph yet) -- so print your `count` and reset it..  If not, it is part of the current paragraph, so add it to `count`.  Finally, once you've finished the file, if `count` isn't 0, you have to print the count of the last paragraph.

Comment: possible to show this in code?. I'm not sure how this works as I'm fairly new to java